# Insert with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, insert

I figured out how to do a multiple table join update but am not clear how to set up as an Insert instead. This was my update:

```
  Update TableA as T1
  Inner Join TableB T2 
  Inner Join TableC T3
  On T3.A=T1.A and T3.B=T2.Band T1.C=T2.C
  Set T1.B=T3.B
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing except I want to insert vs updating a record. Is that possible?

Comment: let us know your table architecture and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`INSERT AS SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) :

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1,Col2,Col3.....)
SELECT t2.Col1,t3.Col2,t3.Col3....
FROM TableB t2
INNER JOIN TableC t3
 ON(t2.band = t3.b)
```

If you want to include/exclude some of `Table1` data so add it to the joins as well.

Comment: The issue is I need to insert Col1,Col2 and I am choosing Col1 from T2 and Col2 from T3. Does this simply mean for T3 I also do select e.g. `Select Col1 from TableB t2 Inner Join (Select Col2 from TableC) t3`

Comment: That's ok, look at my update, just alias in the select where you want to get it from (t2 for tableB , t3 for tableC) @user3649739

Comment: The issue I am encountering is I need to specify fields in each of the joins that allow the on t2=t3 clause to work but I don't need those fields in the update. I'm unclear which part of the select/inner join specifies fields to use for  the on clause and which part corresponds to the Insert col1,coln. I'm testing in Navicat I guess I could push to SqlFiddle if it helps

Comment: The part after the `SELECT <        >` is the columns that getting insert, all the rest is for the join. @user3649739 Replace <Col1,Col2,Col3> in both of the places with the actual columns you need

Comment: If You still don't understand, then yes, make an SQLFiddle and I'll help you. @user3649739

Comment: Got it, didn't make sense at first because I needed more selects to manage the on clause then required for the update but I simply put the necessary t2.field and t3.field first and in the order of the insert and the rest after.